# Get total likes and comments from Instagram's API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

I am currently displaying a range of stats of my Instagram account using their API. I'd like to know how to get the total number of likes and the total number of comments made to this account. Iconosquare (previously Statigram) provides in-depth statistics to your Instagram account - I'd like to take a similar approach to display the two stats in a div. Any support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the Instagram API provides these aggregates. You'll prob. have to lookup all the media for the account and add them together.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to get like and comment count for all photos by a user, you can get total likes and comments for each photo, so you will have to loop through all the photos from a user and then then add the total likes and comments.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{USER_ID}/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID
```

This API will give photos from a user with pagination, add all likes and comments from photos.

Comment: This returns only the recent photos. Is there a way to return all the photos from an user?

Comment: use pagination "next_url" in api response to get next 20 photos